# Elasticsearch java RestHighLevelClient "Unable to parse response body" IllegalArgumentException: Required [index]

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, indexing, client

I'm dealing with a problem when creating an index using the java **RestHighLevelClient** in **Elasticsearch** and my **CreateIndexResponse** object is in consequence null.

I am actually able to create the index, which I can confirm later querying it, but when I create the index, I get this exception. Here my code:

```
`CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("myindex"); 
CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(request);`
```

Elasticsearch returns the message of success with:

```
`HTTP 200 Success

{
  "acknowledged": true,
  "shards_acknowledged": true
}`
```

And I am actually able to retrieve the index later with a GET call, but when the **RestHighLevelClient** tries to parse the response, using the following internal call:

```
//Type of the response converter: CheckedFunction<Req, Request, IOException>    requestConverter
responseConverter.apply(response);
```

The following exception happens:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to parse response body for 
Response{requestLine=PUT /myindex?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s HTTP/1.1, 
host=http://localhost:9200, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK}
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:507)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:474)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.create(IndicesClient.java:77)
at hello.client.HelloClient.createSynch(HelloClient.java:84)
at hello.main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required [index]
```

So basically what this is saying is that the following response cannot be parsed, but for me it looks pretty parsable:

```
Response{requestLine=PUT /myindex?master_timeout=30s&timeout=30s HTTP/1.1, 
host=http://localhost:9200, response=HTTP/1.1 200 OK}
```

Why does it tell me that the index is missing? Is it that I'm using wrongly the java client? This is the version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I had the same error when I used older verson of Elasticsearch than the client was. That was a compatibility problem, see the solution for that: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exception-during-create-index-operation-using-java-high-level-rest-client/123108 What ES version do you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864658/anime answered with the best fix. Must resolve this one.

Answer (score 11):

You need to either update your version dependency or add compatibility headers (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/) as for my case even latest version of Spring-data-elastic search doesn't support version 8+ of Elastic Search. Had to configure my client like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "*")
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig {

  @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
  private String host;

  @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
  private int port;

  @Value("${elasticsearch.protocol}")
  private String protocol;

  @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
  private String userName;

  @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
  private String password;

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider))
            .setDefaultHeaders(compatibilityHeaders());

    return new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
  }

  private Header[] compatibilityHeaders() {
    return new Header[]{new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"), new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7")};
 }
```

}

Comment: I am getting error in writing the custom header function, can u please let me know the library used for that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that needs to be considered here.
Below example consists of code use to connect to Elasticsearch 8.5 cluster.

1. Addition of custom header

   ```
    @Bean(name = "client", destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {

        String uri = applicationConfig.getElasticSearchDB();
        String[] hosts = uri.split(Constants.COMMA);
        List<HttpHost> httpHosts = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(hosts).forEach(a -> httpHosts.add(new HttpHost(String.valueOf(a.split(Constants.COLON)[0]), Integer.parseInt(a.split(Constants.COLON)[1]), "http")));

        HttpHost[] esHosts = new HttpHost[httpHosts.size()];
        httpHosts.toArray(esHosts);

        return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient
                .builder(esHosts)
                .setDefaultHeaders(compatibilityHeaders()));
    }

    private Header[] compatibilityHeaders() {
        return new Header[]{
                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7"),
                new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.elasticsearch+json;compatible-with=7")
        };
    }
   ```
2. Validating dependency module

- If `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` is used as a dependency, please check the valid version you need using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch
- In my case, because I'm using Elasticsearch version 8.5, I had to use the below in my POM. You can check the `Compile Dependencies` portion in the above webpage to check which version you need to be using.

  ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue using the opensearch, for me - I upgrade the jar dependency version :https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/java/. then the issue is gone.